# What's the benefit of pursuing PhD research at a foreign university vs staying in the home country?

Tags: phd, research-process

If I work on a topic and in a field that is also available in my home country, then why stay in a foreign country?

For example, I work in computational materials science. Many researchers in my home country work in this field. If the quality of work is the same in my home country and in a top ranked university in the US, what's the incentive in pursuing research for 5-7 years in a foreign country, living away from family and suffer from loneliness/homesickness?

Assumption: The advisors in the US and in the home country are of equal reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes in the Academia mobility is evaluated "very good" just for the sake of itself, without adding any decent thought to it.

In fact there is no point, as you say, unless you feel the reputational burden of considering worthwhile things only if coming from the medieval but highly technological country of the USA.

On the other hand, being immersed in a different scenario for prolonged times really help lateral thinking and motivating oneself and to put at ease its own inner person. We as persons are constantly changing.

Considering your situation, you do not need to move abroad to do that, but you better leave the door open for some extended period abroad during your PhD, something like 3 or 6 months in the US. Keep your eyes open for scolarships allowing that, or discuss it with your potential PhD advisor at the interview stage (later is too late ... you need to put already on the table the discussion about reserving funds, evaluate them in at least 1000eur flights + 1000/1500eur per month above your salary for an US stay, and time for that)

Comment: I think I agree to the sentiment of this answer, but maybe not really the way you phrased it. I think there are indeed very good reasons mobility is evaluated as very desirable in Academia (benefits of being exposed to different research culture). The problem is that the profile of an average PhD student _and_ academic has vastly changed from the system originally geared towards a bachelor Oxybridge academic (or one with a partner that runs the household while the researcher... frolics), for whom mobility did not include great life sacrifices, but was more akin to an adventure. (continued)

Comment: So biggest anachronism really is that very frequently requirements for mobility are formal, immutable, irreplaceable and consider candidates without context. Mobility as become a _proxy_ for the skills one could obtain through mobility; if you are lucky, you will actually get evaluated on those skills (adapting to new environments) which you may demonstrate in whichever way. If you're unlucky, a 3-6 month internship/exchange might not be sufficient to tick a box.

Answer (score 2):

On top of agreeing with the answer by EarlGrey about mobility valued for the sake of itself, I'd like to add that there are sometimes specific grants available only if you're coming to country A and only if you haven't been working in country A for the last N years. In the case A is your home country, doing a phd in a foreign country and intending to come back makes you eligible for these grants, unlike the case with doing a phd in your country.

Of course, yet two other obvious points are the (1) availability of phd positions and the level of competition for them (if any), and (2) salary (or stipendium) which can be very different even across Europe.

Comment: reg (2), remember that 1500 € in Poland can be good, in Delft they would be below poverty level. I mention that because sometimes stipendium are even higher, but without any social guarantee attached (i.e. unemployment benefits, quite useful after your PhD, often used to close the thesis in Germany, or at least they are psychologically good if you have to leave your PhD because of personal/working issues with your supervisor).
Money have always a relative value ;)